# Как показывать разную информацию в зависимости от платформы с которой заходит пользователь на сайт?

Tags: javascript

подскажите как можно реализовать показ разной информации в зависимости от платформы с которой заходит пользователь на сайт.

Давненько попадался сайт где при выборе скачивания приложение выбор происходил автоматически. То есть захожу на сайт c windows мне показывает только что я могу скачать для windows. Захожу на сайт с Android мне показывает что я могу скачать только для Android. Mac/IOS - аналогично.

Я думаю смысл понятен, только мне за место скачивание нужно показывать разный текст.

Comment: Сервер на `Node.js`?

Comment: @ksa Нет обычный js

Comment: Т.е. браузерный скрипт должен будет определять операционку клиента? Можно использовать свойство `navigator.appVersion` или `navigator.userAgent`.